# SQL Server 2014 export CSV file issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched for an answer on this, but have come up short. When exporting a table from SSMS, from time to time some of the larger files will have issues where something like an address will trigger a CR/LF and spread a record like an address across multiple rows in the exported CSV file. If I copy an paste the record directly from SSMS and paste it into another program such as word, it will do the same thing. I cant exactly put my thumb down on what is happening here. Other records will export correctly, and then all the sudden one of the records will come up like below...

Looks something like this:

```
1|"Apartment Katha
2|Flat No 9999 Garia Place
3|West Bengal"
```

But I need it like this

```
1|"Apartment Katha Flat No 9999 Garia Place West Bengal"
```

I use Unicode and `"` as the text qualifier.

Comment: If you see new lines in the export then surely there are new lines in the corresponding field - note you will not see these in SSMS grid view.  Create a procedure that does an update-replace & clean the data and beef up the insert logic to prevent future occurrences.

Comment: Thank you Alex K. I guess this issue with this is I'm not exactly sure what I am looking for to update/replace? Is there a hidden character or something that would be causing this?

Comment: chars 13/10 or 10 on its own can represent new lines, see if your data contains any:  `select fld from tbl where charindex(char(13), fld) + charindex(char(10), fld) > 0` - view the resutls as text instead of grid will show them as they are.

Comment: Sure enough, this did the trick. I had never heard of this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CR and LF [in SQL server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql) are `Char(10)` and `Char(13)` Try to take out these characters from your records, and see if it works:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@str, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
```

Comment: Replace with a space else you will run lines together in an irrecoverable fashion.

Comment: @AlexK. good shout, I edited the answer. However, it would be good to know the use case to understand if the space is more relevant than an empty string.